# Symfony CreateProccess Error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, phpstorm

I started using Symfony today and I wanted to use the CLI. So I have installed PHPstorm. Followed all instructions. Added an up to date php 5.4

Now when I try to run:

```
> $ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

Cannot run program "$" (in directory "E:\wamp\www\Symfony"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the specified map

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit**

```
> php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
Cannot run program "php" (in directory "E:\wamp\www\Symfony"): CreateProcess error=2, Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden

> php.exe app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
Cannot run program "php.exe" (in directory "E:\wamp\www\Symfony"): CreateProcess error=2, Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden
```

I tried the answers, but it doesn't seem to change anything! Is this a bigger thing?

**EDIT 2 SOLVED SO FAR**

```
> c:\full\path\to\your\php.exe app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

That piece saved my life, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

As there $ normally means your terminal invitation. And you try to run command '$' with the rest of string being parameters.

```
> c:\full\path\to\your\php.exe app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

OR add path to php to  `%PATH%`

Comment: So how should I change it? I just copied it from The documentation from SimFony : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html

Comment: Yes you should not use $ as it is console invitation.

Comment: The only thing that changed is from $ to php. The error is in dutch (but it is the same)

Comment: Make sure that path to your php exists in %PATH%. Otherwise you would have to do `c:\path\to\php.exe ...`

Comment: Updated my answer with new info

Comment: It isn't still fixed. But I think the problem is the PATH. Tomorrow with new energy I go figure this out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`$` is just a markup showing that this is run in console. If you are running this on Windows, you should do it like this:

```
php.exe app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

To make php work in CLI, you need to add the path to it's binary (where php.exe resides) to PATH.

Comment: I think this is indeed the problem. I gonna fix it tomorrow.