# PHP in Windows system

Tags: php, symfony

I started learning Symfony2 and in a tutorial, which I read, I must do some things in console with PHP like the following:

```
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml
```

But my system doesn't recognize this order. I have installed XAMPP with PHP and MySQL and I can run applications written in PHP. What I need to do with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869995/symfony-createproccess-error Maybe you can do a little with the information on my (older) question

Answer (score 1):

You need to add PHP to your %PATH% variable.

You'll want to add the directory php.exe is located in, like this:

"c:\xampp\php\"

by following the directions here:
http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml